# How to use Apollo Server 2 with Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, graphql, apollo-server

I was studying how to use Apollo GraphQL server with Firebase functions and I found this [link](https://codeburst.io/graphql-server-on-cloud-functions-for-firebase-ae97441399c0), which uses Apollo Server 1. I'm trying to use Apollo Server 2, but it doesn't have

```
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';
```

that the author used in the article.

I've tried to implement in this way:

```
import { https } from "firebase-functions"
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();

const graphQLServer = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

graphQLServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

export const api = https.onRequest(app);
```

with `"apollo-server-express": "^2.0.0"` but without success, because I always get `Cannot GET /` every time I follow function link.

So, is there a way to implement Apollo Server 2 with Firebase/Google Functions?

Comment: Any luck? I have it running locally but once I deploy the function I get the same error

Comment: @RichEBee check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works when I add `path: '/'` to `applyMiddleware`

```
graphQLServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/' });
```

I consume this function when deployed with endpoint `// https://us-central1-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/api`. Playground works fine here.

At `localhost`, by `http://localhost:5000/<project-name>/us-central1/api`. Playground doesn't work here until I change URL beside History button to `http://localhost:5000/<project-name>/us-central1/api/`